# kworker taking 100% of one core

Tags: upgrade, cpu, process

I updated from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04.   I have a quad core, and one core is pegged at 100% usage because of kworker.

I know that kworker generally is doing things on behalf of the kernel, but I don't know how to determine what the issue is.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running any processor-intensive process? Is a restart of the system possible?

Comment: Also impacting me - I have a quad core and two of the cores are at 100% both with kworker, following an upgrade from 13.10. Looks to me to be an issue with 14.04.

Comment: Did you select encryption when you installed ubuntu 14? I just had the same issue when I did this and shared one of the encrypted drive's folders through NFS and mounted it on a Virtualbox instance on the same machine. The solution for me was to share files via SSHFS instead.

Comment: I did not add encryption, and it looks like if I disable the NFS-kernel-Server it goes away.   When I start it up again, it comes back to taking one of my cores.

Comment: I am linking a bug related in conjunction with NFS-kernel-Server https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1322407

Comment: Just to let you guys know that I had the same issue and disabling nfs-kernel-server helped, but it was not a permanent option. I had Ubuntu 12.04 Server as my VM and Ubuntu 14.04 as my host. After upgrading my VM (ubuntu 12.04 server) to the latest patches using sudo apt-get upgrade, the problem disappeared. There must have been some fix -- not sure.